# Implementar login usando credenciales de SQL Server en ASP.NET - MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, login

Buenas,

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con ASP.NET - MVC y SQL Server. No tengo mucha experiencia con estas tecnologías por lo que puede que mi pregunta sea producto de mi falta de instrucción.

**¿Se puede implementar un login en la aplicación que se base en las credenciales de SQL Server?**

Actualmente la aplicación conecta con la base de datos subyacente mediante una `connectionStrings` que ingresa un usuario y contraseña de SQl Server. La idea que intentamos implementar es que, cuando la aplicación se encuentre en uso, cada usuario poseerá una credencial de SQL Server (tarea a cargo de un DBA) con la cual accederá a la aplicación, a la vez que a la base de datos que ésta utiliza.

He estado leyendo acerca de como implementar un **login** usando un esquema basando en SQL Server:

**Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server (C#)**
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

Sin embargo no he encontrado algo que me deje en claro si lo que planteo es posible. Agradecería cualquier guía respecto al tema.

Gracias por su tiempo.
¡Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido Bhelic, te recomiendo que hagas [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y veas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), debieras adjuntar el código de lo que intentaste hasta ahora para que podamos ayudarte mejor. En lineas generales las respuesta a tu pregunta es afirmativa, pero ya te digo, con el código va a ser más fácil que obtengas una respuesta precisa.